# Pontryagin Maximum principle for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

During an online seminar, one of the speakers stated that contrarily to the optimal control problems arising in ordinary differential equations (ODEs). For partial differential equations we can't derive a general Pontryagin Maximum Principle as in the ODEs case and the difficulty of the optimal control problem depends on the PDE.

***What makes the generalization of Pontryagin Maximum Principle difficult to derive in the case of PDEs?***